# NetworkManager VPN timeout

Tags: networkmanager, vpn, openconnect

I have a strange issue with NetworkManager. My Linux box is an openSUSE LEAP 15. 
Network is provided by NetworkManager.
The local ethernet connection has static configuration.

And I have a VPN connection, based on the openconnect client. Without certificates, just Username/Password.

My problem is that the VPN connection drops every now and them. From the logs, it appears to be a "timeout" setting.

```
Oct 29 12:43:30 ws.example.com openconnect[13916]: Received server disconnect: b0 'Idle Timeout'
```

But, the nmcli shows no timeout:

```
vpn.timeout:                            0
```

I struggle to understand why this is happening. I have **exactly the same configuration in a Fedora 27 & a Fedora 28**. The 2 Fedoras are not disconnected, even if I leave the machines idle for hours!

In terms of packages, the Fedora 28 are:

- NetworkManager-vpnc-1.2.6-1.fc28.x86_64
- plasma-nm-vpnc-5.13.5-1.fc28.x86_64
- vpnc-0.5.3-31.svn550.fc28.x86_64

The Leap 15:

- vpnc-0.5.3r550-lp150.1.10.x86_64
- plasma-nm5-vpnc-5.12.6-lp150.3.3.1.x86_64
- NetworkManager-openvpn-1.8.2-lp150.2.1.x86_64

So, the questions are:

1. Is there any general "keep-alive" option in the NetworkManager that I could use in order to stop this timeout thing?
2. Apart from a hack that will use ping or anything similar, is there any other place where I should take a look in case there is a keep-alive directive that I could use with the vpn?

Comment: What type of VPN?

Comment: openconnect. The VPN is provided by Cisco AnyConnect.

Comment: Does using `--force-dpd=0` or with the dpd value in the VPN server in openconnect solve your problem?

Comment: I don't have control on the VPN server.